# Opening second time popup is displaying at bottom of page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, .net-core

I am displaying one popup when user click on button.

First time when user click at that time, that popup is opening perfectly and displayed at top.

Now user submit form and click on Save button which is at bottom.

Now when user click again at that time, that popup is opening but displaying that bottom part of Save button and not going page up at top.

I have tried different solution's but none working..you can see below code.

```
 function showPopupNew(ob) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            $(ob).modal('show');
            $(ob).focus();
            //$(ob).css({ position: 'fixed', top: '0' });
            //$('#Template-update').show();
            //$('#Template-update').popup('open', { y: 0 })
            //$('body').scrollTop(0);
        }
```

Here you can see, I have tried different solutions but still not working..any idea on this.

Comment: have you tried `z-index` with fixed position? Also check for javascript error on console.

Comment: what z-index I need to set ?

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this functionality

Using .scrollTop(0);